# Run a command in ccnet.config

Tags: command, nuget, config, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to run the nuget command that I would normally set in the projects post build `$(ProjectDir)nuget\pack.bat $(ProjectDir)  $(TargetDir) $(ConfigurationName) $(SolutionDir)` to run instead in the ccnet.config on a successful build. What I have does not seem to be running at all.

```
  <exec>
    <Target>
      <executable>cmd</executable>
      <buildArgs>/C c:\build\project\nuget\pack.bat c:\build\project\  c:\build\project\bin\nuget\ Nuget c:\build\project\ /M</buildArgs>
    </Target>
  </exec>
```

Edit
Figured it out partially. Needed to make sure I was pointing to `<executable>c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</executable>` and not using cmd.

Comment: When you say partially figured it out. What part haven't you got working?

Comment: The issue was with something on my server. The above code worked up until it needed to talk to the other server.